ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import with newest numpy version
I am trying to run this code in VSCode and keep running into this error message:

A module that was compiled using NumPy 1.x cannot be run in
NumPy 2.1.2 as it may crash. To support both 1.x and 2.x
versions of NumPy, modules must be compiled with NumPy 2.0.
Some module may need to rebuild instead e.g. with 'pybind11>=2.12
If you are a user of the module, the easiest solution will be to
downgrade to 'numpy<2' or try to upgrade the affected module.
We expect that some modules will need time to support NumPy 2.

I have already tried to uninstall numpy and reinstall an older version but have had no luck
I am trying to run this code:
import numpy as np
import sklearn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(0)
from sklearn import datasets
X, y = datasets.make_classification(n_samples=100, n_features=2, n_informative=2,      n_redundant=0)
X[:,0] = np.abs(X[:,0] * 0.5 + 5)
X[:,1] = np.abs(X[:,1] * 30 + 160)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(X[y == 0, 0], X[y == 0, 1])


What module is that???

Same here!
I used anaconda to install the package.
